# parser error: syntax error, unexpected $data (T_VARIABLE) in codeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, variables

I am newbie in CodeIgniter. When I try to data passing with controller and view and model, I have got this:

> **Syntax error:** Unexpected '$data'(T_VARIABLE) in *c:\xampp\htdocs\ci\application\controllers\users.php* on **line 10**

Here is my controller `users.php` code:

```
<?php
class Users extends CI_Controller
    {
        public function show()
            {
                $data['results']=$this->user_model->get_users();
                $this->load->view('user_view',$data);
             }
    }
?>
```

At views folder `user_view.php` code:

```
<body>
<?php
foreach($results as $object){
    echo $object->username;
}
?>
</body>
```

At model folder `user_model.php` code

```
<?php
class User_model extends CI_Model
    {
        public function get_users()
            {
                $query=$this->db->get('users');
                return $query->result();
            }
    }
?>
```

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do your error says `c:\xampp\htdocs\ci\application\users.php` shouldn't it have been c:\xampp\htdocs\ci\application`\controller`\users.php`

Comment: Thanks for reply. I corrected it. still getting same error.

Answer (score 0):

In your controller

```
public function show()
{
    $data['results']=$this->user_model->get_users();
    $this->load->view('user_view',$data);
}
```

In your model

```
public function get_users(){
    $query=$this->db->get('users');
    $result = $query->result_array(); //added
    return $result; //added
}
```

In view

```
<body>
<?php
    foreach($results as $new_results) //changed
    {
        echo $new_results['username']; //changed
    }
?>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I checked it. But got same error.

Comment: the error is: severity: Parsing Error; Message: Syntax error, unexpected '$data' (T_VARIABLE); Filename: controllers/users.php

Comment: sorry I bother you again. after correcting line I got two message: first one is  Severity:notice;  Message: use of undefined constant result-'result';  Filename:models/user_model.php   and second one is  Severity:Warning;   Message:Invalid argument supplied for foreach();  filename:views/user_view.php

Comment: in view `result` should come `results`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access wrong `ARRAY` in your view.
In your controller array is `$data['results']` not `$data['result']`. So you need to access `$results` in `foreach` loop.

In your `view` Change from

```
foreach($result as $object){
```

To

```
foreach($results as $object){
```

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I changed it but still got same error.

Answer (score 0):

Use `$results` in foreach loop and check

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I changed it and tried but still got same error.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to load your model as:

```
$this->load->model('User_model','user_model');
```

Then you can use the function defined in that model as :

```
$this->user_model->get_users();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have one more error in your code i.e. you have not loaded the model in the function

update your code to add the following line in first line of show() function

```
$this->load->model('user_model');
```